# How do I get snackbar to open more than once?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hooks

I've created a simple codesandbox that demonstrates the issue. Click the button and the MUI snackbar opens. Close the snackbar and try to re-open it. Nothing happens.

Could it have something to do with the way I'm using hooks?

https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-ramanujan-vbnbl

**UPDATE**: here is the 'fixed' code. It now uses React Context to give you a nice 'global' snackbar. https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-wozniak-2pow0

Answer (score 1):

You're using two different sources of data to control visibility and you've confused yourself in the process. Consolidate them into one. You have a click handler that handles this logic, so modify `isOpen` so it is a toggle (instead of always setting to `true`) and pass that function down to be used in `Snacky`.

```
// index.tsx
  const onSubmit = async () => {
    setSnackyProps(prev => ({
      message: "now close me and click the button again",
      variant: "error",
      isOpen: !prev.isOpen
    }));
  };
<Snacky {...snackyProps} onSubmit={onSubmit} /> // highly irrelevant function name. probably want to change it

// snacky.tsx
  {onSubmit} = props
  function handleClose() {
    onSubmit();
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-leftpad-pndo3

Comment: You're totally right, I got myself all confused. Thanks Andrew!

Comment: @JonStevens Always happy to help. Best of luck on your project